# The number of stretches in the vector when the param is equal to 0

Tags: r, vector

How can I find the number of stretches (blocks) in the vector when the `param` is equal to 0? In this example, the answer would be 3.

The vector `param`:

```
param <- c(25, 20, 18, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What happens if you have only one `0`, does it counts or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume a "stretch" is at least two or more values. But with your test data

```
x<- c(25, 20, 18, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 3, 6, 9, 0, 0)
```

I would use the `rle()` function to calculate the run lengths

```
with(rle(x), sum(values==0 & lengths>1))
# [1] 3
```