# The number of stretches in the vector when the value is less than 1

Tags: r, vector, filter, filtering

I asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971486/the-number-of-stretches-in-the-vector-when-the-param-is-equal-to-0). I want to find the number of blocks when the value is less than 1. In the below given example, the answer must be 2.

```
Block #1: 0.2,0.3
Block #2: 0.25959969,0.23051247,0.33962332
```

However, the solution works only if I say `values==0`. If I use less than sign, i.e. `values<1`, then the answer is not correct ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971486/the-number-of-stretches-in-the-vector-when-the-param-is-equal-to-0) 0), while it must be 2.

Here I provide the reproducible example:

```
x <- c(0.2,0.3,9.36401452,7.55982857,6.06992455,4.67168492,3.50976922,2.18683333,1.36610395,0.25959969,0.23051247,0.33962332)

with(rle(x), sum(values<1 & lengths>1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get the "blocks" and the "length" of blocks

```
indx <-  inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x<1), 
                  values <- seq_along(values)))[x<1]

split(x[x<1], indx) 
#$`1`
#[1] 0.2 0.3

#$`3`
#[1] 0.2595997 0.2305125 0.3396233

length(with(rle(x <1), lengths[values]))
#[1] 2
```

Or

```
with(rle(x<1), sum(values & lengths>0) )
#[1] 2
```

If it is `>5`, just replace `lengths>0` by `lengths>5`

```
with(rle(x<1), sum(values & lengths>5) )
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Ok,how can I say that length of blocks must be at least 5? lengths>5